# LinkedEntity polymorphic relationship field not returning data on SOQL

Tags: soql

We have a custom object Client_Intake_Upload__c with custom field Hub_Spoke_Account__c that is connected to ContentDocumentLink  object. The polymorphic relationship field on ContentDocumentLink is called LinkedEntity. When we run the query below, ContentDocumentId and LinkedEntityId get returned but not Hub_Spoke_Account__c (which is not null).

```
SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId , TYPEOF LinkedEntity WHEN Client_Intake_Upload__c 
 THEN Hub_Spoke_Account__c  END FROM ContentDocumentLink 
WHERE LinkedEntityId IN (SELECT Id FROM Client_Intake_Upload__c Where Status__c = 'Uploaded')
```

How can we get Hub_Spoke_Account__c to show?

Comment: although i don't have your object model, when i ran the equivalent in my org; works fine. Are you sure this isn't an artifact of debug log which won't show parent fields returned in a SOQL query?

Comment: How are you trying to read/render the value?

Comment: Adrian, Cropredy: I am just running that SOQL query on Developer Console -> Query Editor